# Why some web pages/files saved to NTFS can be accessed in Ubuntu but not in Windows OS ?

Tags: windows, firefox, filesystem, ntfs

I'm having problem opening files which I saved in Ubuntu with Firefox web browsers *"Save Page As"* in a NTFS partition. The files can be viewed/accessed (using web browsers or text editors or word processors) offline on Ubuntu but not in Windows.

What's the reason? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you saving it into Ubuntu partition then copy it into NTFS partition or you directly save it inito NTFS partition ?

Comment: As same as saving the file directly into NTFS partition happen the same thing if saving it into Ubuntu partition then copy it into NTFS partition. The problem is with FF's "Save As". All the files works perfectly in Ubuntu, sometimes some of the files works in Windows. When I try to open one of the files "broken" in Windows I get "File not found Check the files name and try again".

Comment: Just Web Pages         .

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file-name of the web-page (or other files) that you saved, while using in Ubuntu session, to the NTFS partition contain one or some of the characters listed below:

```
* " : < > ? \ / |
```

and also see whether the file-name is larger than 255 characters. If yes, Windows won't allow accessing <sub>*(but you can in Ubuntu)*</sub> such file as the file-name includes forbidden characters or too large than what is allowed. <sub>Visit the reference links below for more info.</sub>

To avoid this, you should save (save as) the files manually specifying with valid names, which won't include the forbidden characters and contain 255 characters or less.

Also, the FAT file-system does not allow those characters.

#### Reference:

- [Filename Limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations)